# Does every use of a wand require a Use Magic Device check for non-spellcasters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, spellcasting

Does every use of a wand require a Use Magic Device check for non-spellcasters?

For example, for a combat wand user:
Does the user need to make a UMD (use magic device) check and an attack roll every time they use a wand of *scorching ray*?

Answer (score 5):

## Yes.

If we look at [Use Magic Device](https://aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ItemName=Use%20Magic%20Device) we see:

> *Use a **Wand**, Staff, or Other Spell Trigger Item:* **Normally, to use a wand, you must have the wand’s spell on your class spell list.** This use of the skill allows you to use a wand as if you had a particular spell on your class spell list. Failing the roll does not expend a charge.

So in order to use a wand without using Use Magic Device, the character must have the spell on the spell list for any of the classes that character has.

Since the character in question has no classes that have the spell on their spell list, they must made a Use Magic Device check of 20 to use the wand every time they want to use it. If they fail this check with a natural 1, they can't attempt to activate the item again for 24 hours.

Comment: One slight correction, skill checks don't automatically fail on a natural 1, and the 24 hour rule specifically states: "if you ever roll a natural 1 while attempting to activate an item **and** you fail..." which means that with a high enough mod, a natural 1 can still succeed. At which point, it's no longer necessary to roll the check.

Comment: @JonathanBennett there's a reason I say "If they **fail** this check with a natural 1", and while it may not be necessary to roll the check (since they'll pass), they're supposed to roll it according to the rules.